# How do I select a set of specific cells and then copy their entire row?

Tags: windows-xp, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2002

Okay this is hard to explain.

I have a massive spreadsheet with sets of data in it. Each set has 'type' column (eg: system, memory, video card, etc). I need to be able to search within this column for a specific type and then be able to copy the entire row. I need this to work with multiple cells selected and then copy the multiple rows.

Basically, there's around 10 rows, all listing parts of a computer with its serial number, part number, date of purchase, etc, and I need to be able to extract only a few of those rows and put them in a new spreadsheet.

I am using Excel Office XP (2002) on Windows XP SP3.

Here is an example of the data from the spreadsheet: ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoidL.png )
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand from your explanation, but I think what you need is to Filter.

Try selecting your full data set and then goto Data|Filter. That will give you a drop down on your column headings and allow you to chooose only those `Items` that you're interested in.